# How to merge columns from two table structures into one table, and count group by one filed?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, City and Vehicle. Now I want to merge the two tables into one table. Then count each type of vehicle based on city. Then merge them in to one table. Could someone help me?

City:

| City_Id | City_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New York |
| 2 | Washington |

Vehicle:

| Vehicle_Id | Vehicle_Type | City_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Electric | 2 |
| 2 | Fuel | 1 |
| 3 | Fuel | 2 |
| 4 | Fuel | 1 |
| 5 | Electric | 1 |

I want to achieve this. Merge tables City and Vehicle into Vehicle_Count, based on column 'City Name'. Table Vehicle_Count should include City Name, different vehicle types as different columns, total number of vehicles of different vehicle type group by city. If there is no data on each of other table, the value set 0. The column 'Total' is the count of vehicles of all  vehicle type.

Vehicle_Count:

| City_Name | Electric | Fuel | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Washington | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I have tried this SQL

```
SELECT c.City_Name,COUNT(*) AS Electric FROM Vehicle v 
LEFT JOIN City c ON c.City_Id = v.City_Id 
WHERE v.Vehicle_Type = 'Electric'
GROUP BY v.City_Id
```

Only got this

| City_Name | Electric |
| --- | --- |
| New York | 1 |
| Washington | 1 |

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags, please re-tag with the database product you are actually using.

Comment: you can count conditionally `COUNT( CASE WHEN Vehicle_Type = 'Fuel' THEN 1 ELSe 0 END)` but you should think about normalizing your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
SELECT City_Name , Electric, Fuel, total1+total2 AS Total FROM (
SELECT sc.City_Name, COUNT(*) AS Electric, 0 AS Fuel FROM Vehicle si 
LEFT JOIN City sc ON sc.City_Id = si.City_Id 
WHERE si.Vehicle_Type = "Electric" 
GROUP BY si.City_Id 
UNION ALL 
SELECT sc.City_Name,0 AS Electric, COUNT(*) AS Fuel FROM Vehicle si 
LEFT JOIN City sc ON sc.City_Id = si.City_Id 
WHERE si.Vehicle_Type = "Fuel" 
GROUP BY si.City_Id 
) A 
GROUP BY City_Name
```